# Magento checkout method recorded in database

Tags: magento

Is the Magento checkout method recorded anywhere in the database.

I know the value can be accessed during the session i.e. register, guest etc but after the order is placed is the value recorded anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout method is stored in the `sales_flat_quote` table in the `customer_is_guest` field. A value of 1 indicates the customer checked out using the guest checkout option. A value of 0 indicates the customer checked out using their account. You can access the quote using its id from the order object.

Answer (score 0):

Anton S gave a good answer but if you need more help viewing tables and their fields in the Magento database, this is a really useful tool.

http://www.magereverse.com/

Simply select your version of Magento and then start selecting tables.  It gives you correlations between various fields in the tables as well, which can be helpful when tracking down entity data.

Hope this helps!