# Observer for Checkout Start

Tags: magento, observers

Is there an observer in Magento to detect the start of the checkout process?  This would include hitting the page `checkout/onepage/` or `checkout/onestepcheckout/`.  I would like to avoid overriding controllers if possible.

Comment: do you want to establish a customer count or what?

Comment: I want to do some validation on the items in their cart first, and if validation fails, redirect them to the cart page.

Comment: you'll have to do that with php see http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/294962/

Comment: but the checkouts are logged in the db if you want see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985931/magento-checkout-method-recorded-in-database

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Every controller action will result in multiple targeted events which are fired in [`Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action` (link)](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php), the superclass for all action controllers. These events variously involve the "full action name," derived from module router configuration + controller path + action, as well as the route name which is being requested.

In the case of standard onepage checkout, the full action name is `checkout_onepage_index` and the route name is `checkout_onepage`.

**renderLayout():**

`controller_action_layout_render_before_'.$this->getFullActionName()`

**preDispatch():**

`controller_action_predispatch_' . $this->getRequest()->getRouteName()`
`controller_action_predispatch_' . $this->getFullActionName()`

**postDispatch():**

`controller_action_postdispatch_' . $this->getRequest()->getRouteName()`
`controller_action_postdispatch_' . $this->getFullActionName()`

Which events you observe will depend on how the OneStepCheckout module captures routes. The `getRouteName()`-based events may be useful if you need to distinguish between routes and modules. You'll want to test "customer is logged in" and "customer is logged out" scenarios. While the predispatch events are preferred for logic which involves a redirect, you'll want to  balance your needs against duplicating cart/quote + customer session logic.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look @ `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index` event

See ['Proceed to Checkout' Event for Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211119/proceed-to-checkout-event-for-magento)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do it that late? Depending on what you are checking, you might do it after adding them to the cart? `checkout_cart_save_before`

Comment: They could add to cart, see the error message, but still check out anyway.  I need to block checkout completely if conditions are not met, preferentially right at the start.

Comment: you can change the cart, so it meets the conditions. But yes if you don't want to change the cart, you should go on the dispatch event