# Magento Observer on checkout

Tags: php, xml, magento

I just followed a tutorial on how to create a simple model observer. Can someone here help me or point me to the right direction to call the method when the user clicks "proceed to checkout"?

Here is the code:

```
 <events>
  <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
    <observers>
      <sales_order_place_before>
        <type>singleton</type>
        <class>my_Observer</class>
        <method>send_email</method>
      </sales_order_place_before>
    </observers>
  </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>     
 </events>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

Create: app/code/local/MagePal/MyCheckout/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MagePal_MyCheckout>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </MagePal_MyCheckout>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>
            <magepal_mycheckout>
                <class>MagePal_MyCheckout_Model</class>
            </magepal_mycheckout>
        </models>
         <events>
            <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
                <observers>
                    <magepal_mycheckout>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>mycheckout/observer</class>
                        <method>sendEmail</method>
                    </magepal_mycheckout>
                </observers>
            </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

Create: app/code/local/MagePal/MyCheckout/Model/Observer.php

```
class MagePal_MyCheckout_Model_Observer 
{
    /**
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     * @return object
     */
    public function sendEmail(Varien_Event_Observer  $observer)
    {
        //add logic here

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Create: app/etc/modules/MagePal_MyCheckout.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
           <modules>
                  <MagePal_MyCheckout>
                          <active>true</active>
                          <codePool>local</codePool>
                  </MagePal_MyCheckout>
           </modules>
    </config>
```

Comment: @Kornik, mind sharing what the correct answer was? The given answer actually observes when the order is submitted not when the user just proceeds to checkout.

Comment: @ryanmcdonnell ... See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652497/observer-for-checkout-start

Comment: @RenonStewart I have an option like Pick From Store if customer chose pick from store how to remove handling charge, someone post same, could pls help thtat post -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/285128/57334

Comment: @Gem... Without knowing exactly what you are trying to accomplish... The way I would accomplish something like this is to use a special shipping method for local pickup and only apply the handling charge if the shipping method is not local pickup.

Comment: Okay, I understand.